# Did the original Fantomas movies also include a lot of gadgets like the movies from the 60s?

Tags: remake, fantomas

In my childhood I liked the Fantomas-movies from the 60s ([1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058089/combined), [2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059168/combined), [3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060400/combined)) with Louis de Funès as inspector Juve. I can see they are remakes of much older Fantomas-movies from [1913](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0002844/combined), [1932](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0027607/combined) and [1947](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0143246/combined).

I liked in the movies of the 60s the massive use of funny or interesting gadgets, like the third hand or a gun in a peg leg and the extensive use of technological advancement, like submarines and helicopters.

As I never saw the original movies, was this included in them already or new in the remakes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are some gadgets in the 1913 Fantomas. From my own memory, they play not a leading part of the story, but they can be found.

At [youtube you may find a sequence](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXjcnlBPolI), approx at minute 8 you can see a third arm. At the start, you have a sequence with the actors and there changing look.

The 1913 films are available on DVD. http://www.seanax.com/2010/09/20/fantomas-cinemas-first-supervillain/ describes the film:

> Each films is filled with wild plots and demented side schemes and features exotic gimmicks

There you can also find a link to amazon.

The [Giornate 2000](http://www.cinetecadelfriuli.org/gcm/ed_precedenti/edizione2000/edizione2000_frameset.html) includes also a description of the films.